# Python: list comprehension which references an internally generated list

Tags: python

First off, there isn't a question if you break this problem into three steps: 1) create some_list 2) create random_list and 3) run a straight forward list comprehension over the two lists (i.e. `[(x, y, f(y, m)) for x in l for y in m]`. Because of the constraints of some APIs I am working with, I want be able to write the code with two lines: 1) create some_list 2) run a list comprehension which creates the second second list and allows for some operation/function/method against the internally generated list itself.

This is what I would like to be able to do:

```
import random
[(x, y, not random_list.index(y)) for x in some_list
 for y in random.sample([1,2,3,4,5], (random.choice([1,2,3]))) as random_list]
```

I know the `as random_list` doesn't work here. I know if I create a list based on `random.sample([1,2,3,4,5], random.choice([1,2,3]))` before I code the list comprehension, there isn't any problem here.

Writing out the question leads to some answers. Here is the specific answer to the specific problem given above:

```
[(x, y, not i) for x in some_list
 for i, y in enumerate(random.sample([1,2,3,4,5], random.choice([1,2,3])))]
```

My basic question is: if a list is created inside a list comprehension, can that list itself be referenced within the list comprehension? Or do I need to create some kind of wrapper?

```
def wrapper():
    f = lambda i, l: 42
    l = random_list()
    return [(i, f(i, l)) for i in l]

[(x, i, v) for x in some_list for i, v in wrapper()]
```

I think I have largely answered my question, but it seemed like a good one worth writing up. If there are other thoughts, comments, that would be very useful.

@DSM valid question. Here is the particular (django) code:

```
PlayerPosition.objects.bulk_create([
    PlayerPosition(
        player=player,
        position_id=position_id,
        primary=not index
    ) for player in Player.objects.all()
     for index, position_id in enumerate(random_position_list())
])
```

Comment: I'd be very interested in hearing the details of how an API mandates you write code in two lines instead of three.  How does it even know?

Comment: I'd like to know exactly what DSM asked. Also, could you post real code for the correct for-loop version? I think that would make this more concrete.

Comment: @DSM: code provided. @kobejohn: the self answer I gave above using `enumerate()` gave an answer very close to what I was looking for. The `wrapper()` function approximates and abstracts want `enumerate()` does, returning any arbitrary value with the list item, not just the list item's index value.

Comment: just add another layer of iteration or use a zip with a multiplier for the "new" list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you want to create a list, bind it to a name, and then use the name inside a list comprehension. What prevents binding a name in an expression is that assignments are statements. However, you can (ab)use `lambda`s to get what you want:

```
(lambda random_list: [
    (x, y, not random_list.index(y)) 
    for x in some_list
    for y in random_list])(
        random_list=random.sample([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], random.choice([1, 2, 3])))
```

That works in that it's one line of code, but I'm not sure if it works within your other constraints, which are at this point enigmatic and unclear.

---

EDIT: If you can make a helper function then you should almost certainly take that approach. I would do it differently than yours, though. I'd make a generic one like this:

```
def iter_with_list(l):
    for element in l:
        yield (l, element)
```

Using it like so:

```
[(x, y, not random_list.index(y))
 for x in some_list
 for random_list, y in iter_with_list(random.sample([1,2,3,4,5], random.choice([1, 2, 3])))]
```

That way you can still keep all the logic in the comprehension without spreading it all over the place. This is just another trick to bind a name as part of an expression - in this case by repeatedly offering it up to be bound for each iteration of the comprehension - but it's a lot more elegant than the previous one.

Comment: Congratulations, you've turned Python into Lisp.  o_O

Comment: @Wooble: :D. It's almost always possible to do this to any language.

Comment: @Claudiu: you told me very well, and clearly, why python cannot provide me what I want when I first asked my question. As to enigmatic and unclear, I agree because I didn't know how to ask about how to get what I wanted. To me at least, once I figured out how `enumerate()` solved my specific question, I figured out how to generalize. Instead of simply generating a list within the list comprehension, I can write a function which generates both the list items and the value I want to calculate using the list item and the list itself as inputs.

Comment: @Claudiu one of my first thoughts was using a generator function. So you have provided an extra level of insight. Thanks

Comment: @Cole: cool, glad to be of help =). Also note that worst-case you can always construct the list by appending items to it. I really do prefer to use comprehensions but sometimes if I have multiple operations to perform to generate each element I end up doing it the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 1):

> My basic question is: if a list is created inside a list comprehension, can that list itself be referenced within the list comprehension?

Short answer is, yes it can. You can have as many list comprehensions inside list comprehensions as you like, but things will get quite unreadable. Demonstration:

```
>>> [var for var in [val for val in range(1, 100)]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
>>>
```

If you want to combine two lists, as tuples:

You can do something like this:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> zip([x for x in xrange(0, 10)], [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(10)])
[(0, 56), (1, 60), (2, 7), (3, 29), (4, 85), (5, 76), (6, 95), (7, 91), (8, 40), (9, 4)]
```

You can even apply operations on the values of list comprehensions (but it gets *really* unreadable then):

```
>>> weird_list = [val for val in [var for var in xrange(0, 100) if not var % 2] if not val % 3]
>>> print weird_list
[0, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60, 66, 72, 78, 84, 90, 96]
```

With regard to your comment:

```
>>> another_weird_list = [(var, 42) for var in xrange(5)]
>>> another_weird_list
[(0, 42), (1, 42), (2, 42), (3, 42), (4, 42)]
```

No need for a lambda.

In response to your second comment:

Initially:

```
arbitrary_list = [x for x in range(10)]
f = lambda x: [var + 1 for var in x]
no_list = [(var, f(arbitrary_list)) for var in arbitrary_list]
```

Then:

```
no_list = [(var, [var + 1 for var in [x for x in range(10)]]) for var in [x for x in range(10)]]
```

One liner. You can still make an `arbitrary_list` if you want.

Comment: In your first example, `[(var, f(range(1, 100))) for var in range(1, 100)]` works. But `[(var, f(arbitrary_list()) for var in arbitrary_list()]` does not because two different arbitrary lists are created. So I'm not sure how your answer works

Comment: In your second example, you are generating the list twice. It only works because the result of generating it is the same.

Comment: @Claudiu Changed the list :)

Comment: The lambda can return any arbitrary value based on the input. I only used `f = lambda x, list_of_x: 42` to show there could be some calculate against those inputs. How about: `f = lambda, x, list_of_x: x / len(list_of_x)`